# Database management Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3.1, database-management

I'm new to Ruby On Rails, I allways used php to develop websites. With php I used MAMP and Sequel Pro to manage my database.

I would like to use Sequel Pro to manage my Rails database but I can't find the parameters to setup my Sequel Pro. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thijs

Comment: Any particular reason for this? You could use the Rails console (type `rails console` inside a Rails application) to see the database there.

Comment: I don't realy like the console (yet). It would be nice for me to use a visual program.

Answer (score 8):

The parameters to set it up can be found in the `config/database.yml` configuration for the application. By default, Rails applications use SQLite3, and so you'd need to swap your `database.yml` over to using MySQL if you're wanting to use Sequel Pro:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql 
  username: your_username
  password: your_password
  database: your_database
```

You may also need to specify a `socket` parameter as well (underneath database, at the same indentation level). This is usually the case on Ubuntu.

```
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.run
```

From there, you can then run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate` inside your application's folder to create and setup the database. If that works OK, then you should be able to connect to it using Sequel Pro and the credentials that you entered into your `config/database.yml` file.

Comment: Thanks for your super fast response. I'm trying it right now, I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: Not realy.. Apparently using a mysql database (using mamp) is not so trivial.. This post (http://blog.mirotin.net/35/mamp-1-9-5-mysql-5-5-9-and-ruby-mysql2) explains how to set it up, I haven't tested it but it seems to work. Hopes this helps someone else.